# Code for SQL Server Management Studio 2008 plugin

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am looking for some reference code implementing a SSMS 2008 plugin.

Can somebody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this [SSMS Addins project](http://ssmsaddins.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex.com.

Download the DataScripter.zip and look at the source code.

Comment: FYI: The code doesn't compile as it is. There are multiple missing assembly references that need to be fixed first.